# Empty field for integer data type in csv file to big query using Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery, opencsv

I am trying to upload csv file to Big Query table using Java. There are empty fields in the csv file for the integer data type columns. These columns are nullable in the dataset. However, it hit error saying that "Provided Schema does not match Table xxxx. Field STATUS_ATTR_ID has changed type from INTEGER to STRING".

I have tried to convert the empty field to null before load to Big Query but I still get the same error. Below is code

```
public long writeFileToTable(String datasetName, String tableName, Path csvPath, String csvPathString)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, CsvException {

        String projectId = "xxxxx";

        // Authenticate using the service account key
        BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(projectId)
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build().getService();

        // [START writeFileToTable]
        TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
        WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
                WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId)
                        .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv())
                        .setAutodetect(Boolean.TRUE)
                        .setNullMarker("")
                        .build();


        TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigQuery.writer(writeChannelConfiguration);

        File inputFile = new File(csvPathString);

        // Read existing file
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile)));
        List<String[]> csvData = reader.readAll();
        // Write data to writer

        try (OutputStream stream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)) {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(outputStreamWriter);

            for (String[] csvRec : csvData) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= csvRec.length; i++) {
                    if (csvRec[i - 1].equals("")){
                        //csvRec[i - 1] = null;
                    }
                }
                // Write the modified data to the output stream
                csvWriter.writeNext(csvRec);
            }

            // Flush and close the writer (important for the data to be written to the output stream)
            csvWriter.flush();
            csvWriter.close();
            //Files.copy(csvPath, stream);
        }
        // Get load job
        Job job = writer.getJob();
        job = job.waitFor();
        JobStatistics.LoadStatistics stats = job.getStatistics();
        return stats.getOutputRows();
        // [END writeFileToTable]
    }
```

Is it possible to upload csv file containing empty field for integer column to Big Query?

Comment: It is possible to upload csv with empty fields, I have tried it and it just shows as *null*, If possible can you try just uploading the csv file through Bigquery Console ?